# Apache use environment from virtual location

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a little problem.

I want to be able to use a location such as git.my-domain.org/repo-a to set an environment that is used in git.my-domain.org/ as /repo-a is changed to / using a rewrite rule (which I must use?)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.my-domain.org
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/gitweb

    RewriteEngine On

    <Location /repo-a>
        RewriteRule /repo-a(.*) /$1 [PT]
        SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG "/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/repo-a.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl"
    </Location>

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to use a rewrite rule because /usr/share/gitweb/repo-a does not exist (or do I?), and I don't have any intention of creating any directories there. What I want is to use SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG from /daily-backups and use it under /. But it seems that it isn't set, I've also tried using SetEnvIf with no success.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*repo-a" GITWEB_CONFIG "/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/repo-a.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl"
```

There is probably an automated way to use a RewriteRule together with SetEnv so that I don't have to create a new  for another repository?
For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*repo-a" GITWEB_CONFIG "/var/.../$1.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl"
```

I know I can symlink directories and using /var/lib/.../repo-a.git/gitweb/ as a DocumentRoot instead, but I'd rather avoid this as it would increase the number of .conf files (or be very cluttered).

### Question summary

1. Do I need a rewrite rule because the directory doesn't exist?
2. How do I pass an environment variable to another "location"?
3. Is there a way to simplify SetEnvIf or SetEnv to make use of the URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.my-domain.org
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/gitweb

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /(repo-?) / [E=GITWEB_CONFIG:/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/$1.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl,PT]

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This regex only supports `repo-a`, `repo-1` etc. You can widen it but be careful not to swallow too much with `.*` but depends on how the CGI works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. With your help I was able to add any name of the repository, so that I don't need every repository to start with repo-. As you mentioned .* was a bit troublesome but I figured out how to solve it.  
`RewriteEngine On`  
`RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ - [E=GITWEB_CONFIG:/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/$1/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl]`  
`RewriteRule ^/.*/(static/.*)$ /$1 [L]`  
`RewriteRule ^/.*/(gitweb\.cgi) /$1 [L]`  
`RewriteRule ^/.+$ /`

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it worked :) You can show your appreciation with an upvote and accepting my answer :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I would like to upvote you, but I need 15 reputation to vote :/ I'll go through my questions again once I get 15 reputation, although it might take a while.

Comment: hehe, don't worry. Thanks for the accept :)